# Unable to edit a link in top line navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation

I've just migrated from WSS 3.0 to Sharepoint 365, and on the 'home' page, there is a link ("Product Services") in the top navigation bar that is not editable.  I've checked every setting I can think of and can't figure out how to get rid of it.  If I just try to edit links, that link disappears and isn't editable.  The link isn't present on any of the sub-pages like all the others are via inheritable permissions, but it's driving me nuts that I can't get rid of it.  Any help is appreciated.

[image: Missing edit link abi]

Update: I've checked the global settings under Site Settings/navigation as well and can't find the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the site title. You could go to Site Settings-> Title, Description, and Logo, change the title you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check in Settings > Site Settings > Navigation to see if there are any links that could be subsites or anything else. Some of these options don't show up when you use the quick edit navigation controls.

Comment: Added additional screenshot to clarify problem

Answer (score 0):

I experience this problem too. In my case, it is due to caching. I try opening SharePoint online using different browsers (Firefox and Edge) and the recent changes in Global Navigation takes effect in different browsers that I have not used to open SharePoint Online before.
Clearing the browser cache solves this issue in my case. I hope this helps others.